# highlighting a cell in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

i'm fairly new at excel, vba.

if have been trying to get a way around to achieve the below scenario but could not. I've also tried searching a solution online but could not get one.

i have numbers starting from 1,2,3......100 written in column A

and i have cell co ordinate written in cell B1 (for example - A5)

how do i move the cursor to go to value written in cell B1 (which is A5) using VBA

my code :

ActiveCell(2,1).select

Thanks in advance,
Irfan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    Range(Range("B1").Value).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: HI Gary, thank you such quick reply.

this is what i wrote (using a command button):

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range(Range("B1").Value).Select
End Sub

i get the following error everytime i click the commandbutton

method 'range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Make sure that cell **B1** contains the text value *A1*